# Error with new line on Lex - Python

Tags: python, grammar, lexical-analysis, ply

I have a problem with my lexical analyzer built with PLY.

When I pass the code of a for loop to my program, the line break between  `{` and `}` is not recognized. Instead, an error is reported, even though there is a `t_newline(t)` function.

The input to the program is:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
}
```

And, the output of the program is

```
 1 . analizadorLexico.py
 2 . analizadorSintactico.py
 3 . parser.out
 4 . parsetab.py
 5 . prueba1.txt
 6 . cpp.py
 7 . ctokens.py
 8 . lex.py
 9 . yacc.py
 10 . ygen.py
 11 . __init__.py
 12 . lex.cpython-36.pyc
 13 . yacc.cpython-36.pyc
 14 . __init__.cpython-36.pyc
 15 . analizadorLexico.cpython-36.pyc
 16 . parsetab.cpython-36.pyc

File number: 5
5
Escogido el archivoprueba1.txt
LexToken(FOR,'FOR',1,0)
LexToken(PA,'(',1,3)
LexToken(INT,'INT',1,4)
LexToken(ID,'i',1,8)
LexToken(ASSIGN,'=',1,10)
LexToken(NUMBER,0,1,12)
LexToken(END,';',1,14)
LexToken(ID,'i',1,16)
LexToken(LT,'<',1,18)
LexToken(NUMBER,5,1,20)
LexToken(END,';',1,22)
LexToken(ID,'i',1,24)
LexToken(PLUS,'+',1,25)
LexToken(PLUS,'+',1,26)
LexToken(PC,')',1,27)
LexToken(CA,'{',1,28)
Error in '
'
LexToken(CC,'}',2,31)
```

The code is:

```
reservados = ['FOR','AND','OR','NOT','XOR', 'INT', 'FLOAT', 'DOUBLE', 
'SHORT','LONG', 'BOOL']
tokens = reservados + [
        'ID',
        'NUMBER',
        'PLUS',
        'MINUS',
        'TIMES',
        'DIVIDE',
        'DIVE',
        'ASSIGN',
        'LT',
        'MA',
        'LTE',
        'MAE',
        'DIF',
        'PA',
        'PC',
        'ANDC',
        #'ORC',
        'NOTC',
        'MOD',
        'CMP',
        'END',
        'COMMA',
        'CA',
        'CC',
        #'ES'

]
t_ignore = ' \t'
t_ignore_WHITESPACES = r'[ \t]+'
t_PLUS = r'\+'
t_MINUS = r'-'
t_TIMES = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE = r'/'
t_ASSIGN = r'='
t_LT = r'<'
t_MA = r'>'
t_LTE = r'<='
t_MAE = r'>='
t_DIF = r'\!='
t_PA = r'\('
t_PC = r'\)'
t_ANDC = r'\&&'
#t_ORC = r'\||'
t_NOTC = r'\!'
t_DIVE = r'\\'
t_MOD = r'\%'
t_CMP = r'=='
t_END = r'\;'
t_COMMA = r'\,'
t_CA = r'{'
t_CC = r'}'
#t_ES = r'\ '

def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

def t_ID(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
    """
        CONVIERTE CUALQUIER IDENTIFICADOR EN MAYUSCULA EN CASO DE QUE SE 
        HAYA ESCRITO ASÍ
    """
    if t.value.upper() in reservados:
        t.value = t.value.upper()
        t.type = t.value

    return t

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)    
    return t

def t_error(t):
    print ("Error de sintaxis '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)


def buscarFicheros(directorio):
    ficheros = []

    numArchivo = ''
    respuesta = False
    cont = 1

    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(directorio):
        #print('Directorio encontrado: %s' % dirName)
        for fname in fileList:
            ficheros.append(fname)

    for file in ficheros:
        print ("",cont,".",file)
        cont = cont + 1

    while respuesta == False:
        numArchivo = input('\nNumero del archivo: ')
        print (numArchivo)
        for file in ficheros:
            if file == ficheros[int(numArchivo) - 1]:
                respuesta = True
                break

    print ("Escogido el archivo" + ficheros[int(numArchivo) - 1])
    return ficheros[int(numArchivo) - 1]

directorio = r'C:/Users/Carlos/Desktop/for c++/'
archivo = buscarFicheros(directorio)
test = directorio + archivo

fp = codecs.open(test, "r", "utf-8")
cadena = fp.read()
fp.close()

analizador = lex.lex()
analizador.input(cadena)

while True:
    tok = analizador.token()
    if not tok : break
    print (tok)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: No @snakecharmerb, this function should not return anything, if it returns an exception occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most likely explanation is that the error is caused by the Windows line-ending `\r\n`. `\r` is not in your list of characters to be ignored, but no rule handles it so it will trigger an error.

If that is the problem, the simplest solution is to add `\r` to `t_ignore`. (I don't see any point in having both `t_ignore` and `t_ignore_WHITESPACES`, so I'd suggest you remove one of them.)

However, I cannot reproduce the error output you provide. The code in your post does not appear to have any function which might output the string `Error in '...`, so this could just be the result of pasting the output from a different version of the code.